# Why does this after_save not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Pledge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :amount, :presence => true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
  validates :divisor, :presence => true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  before_save :set_pay_this
  after_save :set_pennies


  def set_pay_this
    self.pay_this = self.amount / self.divisor
  end

  def set_pennies
    self.pennies = self.pay_this * 100
  end
end
```

The beforesave set pay this works just fine, but the set pennies stays nil after pledge.save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change after save method to

```
  def set_pennies
    self.update_column(:pennies, self.pay_this * 100)
  end
```

after_save is calling but when you assign value in pennies it is just temporary assigned to object not permanent you have to save the object again.
if you put self.save then there will be a infinite loop so use update column that will bypass callback when you save record

Answer (score 1):

After_save always is called when save anything, use with moderation, and when it is called execute the method set_pennies but dont nothing, I too think that the self.update_column or update_all do what you want.